# Div with dynamic width and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<div style="height:190px;width:1000px;white-space:nowrap;overflow:auto;table-layout:fixed">
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album1.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 1 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album2.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 2 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 3 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album1.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 1 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album2.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 2 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 3 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album1.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 1 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album2.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 2 (2,99€)</a>
    <a style="width:150px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold" href="#"><img src="album3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-bottom:2px"><br>Album 3 (2,99€)</a>
</div>
```

Which is basically a fixed-width DIV with a horizontal scroll bar, what I need to do is to adapt its width to the parent element (a table cell). By setting width:100% it overflows parent container and scroll bars disappear, what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: You should really look into using classes. Like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/WHakm/)

Comment: May be `position: relative;` work for you.

Comment: This is a copy/paste to try I'll use classes later... this is not my question anyways

Comment: @Xriuk I know its not your question, hence it being a comment and not an answer. Also its easier to follow if you used classes, not a block of unnecessary inline styles.

Comment: @Ruddy I know what classes are, and how to use them, this is a fast code as I said...

Comment: @Xriuk Not sure why you are starting to get "rude". But when did you state this was "fast code". And as a user of this website I'm telling you its easier to read if you used classes. You should take that on-board for the next time you post a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `width: auto`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9FSBP/ (notice the div fits into the fiddle's parent div width)

I would also recommend using css classes instead of repeating inline CSS.

Here's an updated fiddle demonstrating it within a td (note max-width is set on the td): http://jsfiddle.net/9FSBP/1/

Comment: Keeps overflowing. It's inside a TD. Yeah, I'm going to use classes this is just a copy/paste for trying.

Comment: Updated the fiddle, see above